# MEF + MVC3 - Showing view always fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view, mef

I'm trying to use MEF + MVC3.

I have 2 projects. One where I should "dynamically" render the other modules and I call it Shell. The second project is where I have a certain module, that I want to load inside Shell.

I was able to dynamically instantiate one controller from the module, using MEF, but everytime it redirects to the View it fails to find it.

Do I have to "copy+paste" the Views from all my modules/plugins to my Shell? Or there is any other solution?

Comment: I get "The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations". This happens because I don't have any View inside my project Shell

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the `.cshtml` (or `.aspx`) view files to the actual application directory.

Views are not compiled into projects; instead, they are read from the web application directory at runtime.

If you want to, you can make your own VirtualPathProvider that reads views from something else.

Comment: There are any orientation on how can I achieve that?

Comment: The VirtualPathProvider override in order to lookup inside module dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.aspx` files then you need to make them an embedded view.